# How long does the loss of Dex to AC from running last?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, movement

A character takes a full-round action to [run](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Run) and loses his Dex bonus to AC.

But does the character *only* lose his Dex bonus to AC until he *stops* running on his turn?  Or does the character lose his Dex bonus until right before the start of his *next* turn?

I ask because unlike some other effects (for example, the feat Power Attack) running does *not* say the that effect (in this case, the loss of Dex bonus to AC) lasts until the character's next turn.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. I edited your question a lot because I think it's a great question, and I wanted it even clearer, but feel free to revert it to your original for whatever reason, like if I've changed the question's intent. Also, if you've an answer of your own to this question, you are welcome to answer it, too, instead of including those positions in the question. (I know answering yourself seems weird, but it's totally legit.) Thank you for your participation and have fun.

Comment: Thank you for shortening it up.  You said exactly what I was trying to get at.  And. I'm horrible at the whole brevity thing.  <heheh>

Answer (score 2):

#### It lasts until you stop running.

The Pathfinder rules in general are *explicit*. If something is not explicitly written in the rules, it's not the case.

> You can run as a full-round action. If you do, you do not also get a 5-foot step. When you run, you can move up to four times your speed in a straight line (or three times your speed if you're in heavy armor). You lose any Dexterity bonus to AC unless you have the Run feat.

As you pointed out in the question, there's no mention of the penalty lasting longer, even though such language is used for other actions. [Fighting Defensively](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Fighting-Defensively-as-a-Standard-Action) and [Charge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Charge) both state that the penalties last "until the start of your next turn". The AC penalty of [Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleave-combat) explicitly lasts "until your next turn". The lack of such language reduces the penalty to the smallest possible scope, which is the duration of the action itself.

I also like to point out that your perception of combat is false. In the game world, every character's turn takes the entire 6 seconds of the rounds duration, and everything happens simultaneously. *Turns* exist only inside the rules, as an abstraction enabling the players (and GM) to deal with multiple characters doing things all at once.

Comment: Your last paragraph completely refutes the first two paragraphs, then.  If the "full action run" encompasses the whole 6 seconds, because your initiative begins a fraction of time before mine, then during my six seconds, if I used a bow attack (ranged), then despite the fact you complete your move of 240" during your initiative, my attack ALSO goes off during that six seconds ... meaning the negative to AC lasts through my initiative/actions.

Comment: I agree with Leriol, but I think your answer is still correct. Just remove your last paragraph since it is not necessary and only adds to the confusion. While it is true that turn order and initiative is designed simply to deal with things happening simultaneously, the order in which things happen does matter.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: this answer seems to be wrong (look at the commentaries), I am verifying my sources before editing it again, please don't take it in consideration for now.

Running is a full-round action, which means it starts at the beginning of your turn and finishes at the beginning of your next turn. You lose your Dex bonus to AC while you are running, so it lasts until it is your turn again and you decide to stop running.

Comment: I know it's terrible, but while a creature takes a [full-round action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Round-Actions) to run, that's different from a *1-round action*, which takes a full-round action *and* until right before the creature's next turn (like [casting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Casting-Time) [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person).)

Comment: As it is worded on "casting time": "A spell that takes 1 round to cast is a full-round action. It comes into effect just before the beginning of your turn in the round after you began casting the spell. You then act normally after the spell is completed." 1 round is just a notation for the casting time, full-round is for the action, but both refer to the same thing.

Comment: Sort of. That section continues: "[C]asting a metamagic version of the spell is a **full-round action** for a sorcerer or bard (except for spells modified by the Quicken Spell feat, which take 1 swift action to cast). Note that **this isn't the same as a spell with a 1-round casting time.** Spells that take a full-round action to cast take effect in the same round that you begin casting, and you are not required to continue the invocations, gestures, and concentration until your next turn."

Comment: (That's not my downvote, by the way. I've not downvoted because the rules are terribly unclear about the whole full-round action/1-round action thing, the above comments just representing how I've always read them. I totally want to be wrong and learn something.)

Comment: It seems that you are right, even it it sounds weird.

Comment: Exactly why I feel the need to ask this question -- reference my reply to MrLemon.  I understand his stance, in his first two paragraphs too, but during my initiative-segment of the round, the other guy IS running at x4 speed ... not standing still .... because the "six second timer is still running".  I agree that it's vague, but it means "run" is OP as heck as the runner is standing still during all other segments (which makes no sense to me).

Comment: I agree with the "full-round action for casting", but the casting does not apply any negative combat factors to the caster, whereas someone choosing to run is running x4 their combat speed AND accepting the loss of their dex to AC to put distance between them and their enemy.  They'r e not running (240" for example) in the split second their initiative goes off, during the six second round.