# How does Undine weaponshaft resolve?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, weapons, races

When a character activates the undine weaponshaft how does the order of actions play out between the successful melee attack and the activation of hydraulic push? As a full round action would the attack happen on the first turn and then the second turn would be the hydraulic push?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### On its turn the undine makes a melee attack then uses *hydraulic push*

The [undine weaponshaft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-and-armor-accessories#TOC-Undine-Weaponshaft) says

> As a full-round action, an undine can make a single melee attack with the weapon and use her [*hydraulic push*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hydraulic-push) spell-like ability against the target of that melee attack. The weapon otherwise functions like a standard weapon of its type....

Although the introductory text to [Full-round Action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Round-Actions) says

> A full-round action requires an entire round to complete. Thus, it can't be coupled with a standard or a move action, though if it does not involve moving any distance, you can take a 5-foot step.

…A full-round action is *different* from a 1-round action, the kind of action required to [cast some spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Cast-a-Spell1) (i.e. [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person), [*summon monster I*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) et al.). A *full-round action* is completed during the creature's turn, while a *1-round action* is completed right before the creature's next turn.

This means the undine takes the full-round action to make an attack with the weapon possessing weapon accessory undine weaponshaft then activates its *hydraulic push* spell-like ability because of the weaponshaft all on the undine's turn (similar to the length of time it takes to make a full attack or take the [run](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79221/8610) action), *without* worrying that it must, instead, for example, wait until right before its next turn for the effect to activate (which would be confusing and maybe impossible, as the foe could, by then, move away, break the weapon, or whatever).

And, yes, I totally agree that it's terrible that there's a *really important* and not-altogether-clear difference between a *full-round action* and a *1-round action*.